# Seleccionar elemento de una lista python

Tags: python

alguien sabría decirme a qué se debe el error 9 señalado en la imágen adjunta?
muchas gracias!
saludos,

Genaro.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No veo imagen adjunta. ://

Comment: Saludos, para que tu pregunta sea respondida debes adjuntar la porción de código donde tienes problemas y el error que éste muestra. Revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para más información. ;)

Comment: Ahora se ve la imagen??

Comment: No uses imágenes para mostrar código o mensajes de error pues como notas no se ven, edita y agrega todo eso como texto

Comment: **Nunca** añadas código en imágenes.

Answer (score 4):

Ese error se debe a que estás iterando directamente sobre la lista y tus condicionales se basan en comparaciones con los indices (numéricos). Un ejemplo:

```
elementos = ["Pintura","Mesa","Cereal","Martillo","Revista","Bombillo","Silla"]

for i in elementos:
    print(i)
```

En este código tenemos una lista de elementos, el el ciclo `for` **hacemos que `i` tome el valor de cada uno de estos elementos**. Entonces imprimiendo `i` con `print(i)` dentro del bucle nos tendía que dar como resultado la impresión de todos los elementos.

**El resultado:**

```
Pintura
Mesa
Cereal
Martillo
Revista
Bombillo
Silla
```

Veamos que pasa si intentamos imprimir los valores por indice:

```
  File "C:\Users\gabriel\Desktop\ejemplo.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(elementos[i])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Nos topamos que este error, esto se da por que intentamos acceder al elemento con el indice `i`. Como ya había aclarado anteriormente, `i` toma el valor de cada uno de los elementos, entonces el ciclo interpreta lo siguiente:

```
print(elementos["Pintura"])
print(elementos["Mesa"])
print(elementos["Cereal"])
...
```

Ahora tiene sentido la frase *list indices must be integers or slices, not str*, los indices tiene que ser números enteros o rangos entre números enteros, **no cadenas de texto**

Intentemos otro experimento, veamos que pasa si iteramos sobre el rango de la longitud de la lista:

```
for i in range(len(elementos)):
    print(elementos[i])
```

**El segundo resultado:**

```
Pintura
Mesa
Cereal
Martillo
Revista
Bombillo
Silla
```

Obtenemos por pantalla todos los elementos de la lista, esto por que accedemos a los indices de la lista con `i`, esta vez i es un número entero.

**¿Por qué `i` ahora es un número entero?**

Con [`range()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-range-function/) se puede obtener una lista de los argumentos que especifican, y con [`len()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/len) se obtiene la longitud de un elemento (la cantidad de elementos). Entonces estamos iterando sobre una lista de números, una que tiene los valores de uno en uno hasta el último indice de la lista en cuestión. Comprobemoslo:

```
for i in range(len(elementos)):
    print(i)
```

**La salida:**

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

**Respondiendo a tu pregunta:**

Obtienes ese error por que en los condicionales dentro del bucle `for` comparas con los elementos de la lista con el indice `i`. Para solucionarlo hay dos manera:

a. Iterar sobre el rango de la longitud de la lista.

b. Comparar directamente el elemento.

**Solución a:**

```
for i in range(len(lista)):
    if lista[i] == "rojo":
        rojo = rojo + 1
    elif lista[i] == "azul":
        azul = azul + 1
    elif lista[i] == "amarillo":
        amarillo = amarillo + 1
    elif lista[i] == "verde":
        verde = verde + 1
```

**Solución b:**

```
for i in lista:
    if i == "rojo":
        rojo = rojo + 1
    elif i == "azul":
        azul = azul + 1
    elif i == "amarillo":
        amarillo = amarillo + 1
    elif i == "verde":
        verde = verde + 1
```

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

"for i in lista:" significa que la variable "i" toma los valores de "lista".

"lista" contiene strings: "rojo", "amarillo", "amarillo". Por tanto, "i" toma los valores "rojo", "amarillo", "amarillo". Esos son strings, no enteros. No puedes usar string para indexar listas.

Para contar los colores, usa "i" en vez de "lista[i]" dentro del "for"

```
for i in lista:
   if i == "rojo":
      ...
   elif i == "amarillo":
      ...
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), para que aprendas a responder una pregunta de la manera adecuada.

Answer (score -1):

Hay una manera màs general de lograr el resultado buscado.

Este còdigo buscara el máximo número de ocurrencias en cualquier lista de colores que le pases.

Se usa un diccionario para contar los colores. Asi evitas tener que predeclarar variables individuales por cada posible color. O puedes contar cualquier otra cosa que se te ocurra; no solo colores.

Por cada color recibido, el codigo chequea si ya existe en el diccionario. Si existe, le suma uno al valor acumulado. Si no existe, agrega una entrada al diccionario con valor 1.

Ojo: si escribes "max(dic)", buscara entre las llaves del diccionario (entre los nombres de los colores) y retornara el máximo alfabético. Tú quieres el máximo entre los valores, por lo que dices "max(dic.values())"

```
def color_frecuente(lista):
    ''' Crear un diccionario vacio, indexado por color
        conteniendo el numero de veces que aparece
    '''
    dic = dict()

    for color in lista:
        if color in dic:
            ''' Si el color ya esta presente en el diccionario,
                sumamos una ocurrencia mas
            '''
            dic[color] += 1
        else:
            ''' Primera vez que aparece el color. Agregar una
                entrada al diccionario con valor 1.
            '''
            dic[color] = 1
    ''' Buscar el maximo entre los valores del diccionario, no 
        entre las llaves
    '''
    return max(dic.values())

print(color_frecuente(["rojo", "amarillo", "amarillo"]))
```

Comment: La idea del sitio es crear una base de conocimientos a base del problema planteado, no dar soluciones al problema directamente.